# pass arguments to function in a boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

This is my first time using the boost thread function and prior to this I have little knowledge of working with multiple threads. I attempting to run a second instance of a function alongside the initial call so I can pass two different variables to the same function, which I'm hoping speeds my program up. with the code I have know I keep getting a C2784 Error which says

```
'T *boost::get_pointer(const boost::scoped_ptr<T> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::scoped_ptr<T> &' from 'const std::string'
```

here's the snippet of code that deals with the thread creation

```
string firstPart = recText.substr(1,(subPart1-1));
string secondPart = recText.substr(subPart1,subPart1);

boost::thread firstThread;
boost::thread secondThread;

firstThread = boost::thread(&Conversion::conversion,firstPart);
secondThread = boost::thread(&Conversion::conversion,secondPart);
firstThread.join();
secondThread.join();
```

edit

```
void Conversion::conversion(string _Part)
{
int value_Part = 1;
int valueShort = 0;
int value = checkValue;
if(value == value_Part)
{
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `Conversion::conversion` look like?

Comment: @juanchopanza the whole function is pretty lengthy but that's how it's defined/starts if you want more I can add it

Comment: Is `Conversion::conversion` a member function?

Comment: yes its not the constructor if that's what your wondering. Its a member of the class Conversion. I hope that's what you meant by your question I'm not really sure

Comment: OK, that is a problem. I added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member functions take an implicit first parameter of type (cv qualified) `T*`, where `T` is the class with the member function. You need to pass a pointer to a `Conversion` instance, for example,

```
Conversion c;
firstThread = boost::thread(&Conversion::conversion, &c, firstPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `boost::bind`.

```
Conversion *conversion_obj_ptr = ...
boost::thread firstThread;
firstThread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&Conversion::conversion, conversion_obj_ptr, firstPart);
```

This is assuming that Conversion::conversion is a member function.  If Conversion::conversion is not a member function then leave out the conversion_obj_ptr parameter.

*Edit*

As others commented you don't need to use `bind`, the `boost::thread` constructor will do that for you.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor

Comment: okay, just not sure whats expected after *conversion_obj_ptr =

Comment: You don't actually need to use `bind` here.

Comment: @PeterR - the constructor binds arguments together.