# Passing abstract overridden method to Boost::Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have an abstract class, `simModbusServer`, which has an abstract method, `run()`. It also has this method:

```
void simModbusServer::start() {    
serverThread = boost::thread(&simModbusServer::run);
}
```

This is of course called in a subclass of `simModbusServer`, am I correct to assume that this will create a thread on the subclasses `run()` method which overrides the abstract method of `simModbusServer`?

Comment: That would not even work for a non-virtual member function. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087463/pass-arguments-to-function-in-a-boostthread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to use `boost::bind`, since `run()` is a member function, and it accepts an implicit `this` pointer:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void simModbusServer::start() {    
    serverThread = boost::thread(
        boost::bind(&simModbusServer::run, this));
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

With newer versions of Boost, it seems you can also pass `this` directly as the second argument to the constructor of `boost::thread` (which is what you would do if you were using `std::thread`), as shown below:

```
void simModbusServer::start() {    
    serverThread = boost::thread(&simModbusServer::run, this);
}
```

In that case, you would not need Boost.Bind.

Comment: I don't think you need `boost::bind`. See link in my comment to the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Just pass `this` as the second argument? That's what you would do with `std::thread`, but I kind of remembered `boost::thread` worked differently. Perhaps I'm just confusing things

Comment: I think a long time ago it used to be the case (and at some point, I thought the same, until someone else in SO corrected me IIRC).

Comment: @juanchopanza: OK, thank you - I edited the answer. I need to refresh my knowledge of Boost :)

Comment: Thanks, I figured I needed something like this.